# Fetching a JSON isn't working with no error shown

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

Hey I've this simple code which ought to work, but for some reason it doesn't. I'm guessing the issue is because of using a school computer for this particular program, which does have a lot of things blocked, as well as that it's in an online editor called Replit.com.

Here is the `async` function I'm using to get access to JSON document, everything until the `.json()` method works as checked by `console.log`s

```
const fetchingData = async (apiLink) => {
  const responseFlow = await fetch(apiLink);
  const data = await responseFlow.json();

  locationWeather(data);
}

fetchingData(apiUrl);
```

Rest assured `apiUrl` is valid, as I've checked by pasting it in the search bar which it resulted in the file showing up

Alas the Replit.com editor doesn't show error messages like the dev tools (It's blocked), nor do most other web editors

The `locationWeather` function

```
const locationWeather = (data) => {
  const { temp, feels_like, temp_min, temp_max } = data.main;

  document.querySelector('#temperature').textContent = temp;
}
```

Comment: You might be right with your guess about the school computer. But it could also be a CORS issue. Have a look into your console and network windows when you run the `fetch()` command.and look for errors there.

Comment: Looks like it ought to work ok, so the school computer may be the issue, or CORS like @cars10m said: https://jsfiddle.net/fq2s5k86/

Comment: @cars10m I'd if I could, but again the replit's console is useless, and the dev tools are blocked.

Comment: @user101289, I'm not sure what do you mean by CORS issue? By the way the outcome in the jsFiddle link that you have shown is also blocked.

Comment: Would something like an iframe fix the problem?